# Sybase Temporary Table and Indexes

Tags: performance, sybase, indexing

Is this a misconception?

Sybase query optimizer can not consider index on temporary table if it is created and used in same batch or procedure.

I'm a bit confused about this as there seem to be differing opinion.

Thanks heaps.

Answer (score 1):

That's quite simple.

The optimizer calculates the query plan before execution and the temporary table is created when executing the stored procedure.

A way to pass this problem is to create the temporary table and its index before the execution of the stored procedure :)